# Where does luakit keep my bookmarks file?

Tags: bookmarks

I installed luakit from the repos (`sudo apt-get install luakit`) and it seems to work fine, remembering my bookmarks and everything. The trouble is, I can't figure out where it stores this data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be in your Home folder in `~/.local/share/luakit/bookmarks`.